# Numpy: randomly choose 1 sample from each of the N discrete probability distributions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2-D Numpy array `P` where each `P[ii,:]` is a discrete probability distribution over 0,1,...,M-1. I would like to sample from each of the `P[ii,:]`'s once. I've tried to use the `numpy.random.choice` function:

```py
for ii in range(N):
    samples[ii] = np.random.choice(np.arange(M), p=P[ii,:])
```

How can I do the same thing without for loop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
import numpy as np

P = np.array([[0,1/2,1/2],[1,0,0],[1/3,1/3,1/3]])

def rand_choice(c):
  return np.random.choice(c.size, p=c)

samples = np.apply_along_axis(rand_choice, 1, P)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please show me how to use np.apply_along_axis? Specifically how to supply the argument via **kwargs?

Comment: @Smile, can you provide an example of P? I'm finding it difficult to know how it's created

Comment: for example P = np.array([[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])